# Average day of month range for bill date

Tags: t-sql

Our billing system has a table of locations.  These locations have a bill generated every month.  These bills can vary by a few days each month (ex. billed on 6th one month then 8th the next).  They always stay around the same time of the month, though.  I need to come up with a "blackout" range that is essentially any day of month that location has been billed over the last X months.  It needs to appropriately calculate for locations that may bounce between the end/beginning of months.

For this the only relevant tables are a Location Table & a Bill Table.  Loc Table has a list of locations with LocationID being the PK.  Other fields are irrelevant for this I believe.  There's the bill table that has a document number as the PK and LocationID as a FK.  Also, with many other fields such as doc amount, due date, etc.  It also has a Billing Date, which is the date I'd like to calculate my 'Blackout' dates from.

Basically we're going to be changing every meter, and don't want to change them on a day where they might be billed.

**Example Data:**

**Locations:**

111111, Field1, Field2, etc.

222222, Field1, Field2, etc.

**Bills (DocNum, LocationID, BillingDate):**

BILL0001, 111111, 1/6/2018

BILL0002, 111111, 2/8/2018

BILL0003, 111111, 3/5/2018

BILL0004, 111111, 4/6/2018

BILL0005, 111111, 5/11/2018

BILL0006, 111111, 6/10/2018

BILL0007, 111111, 7/9/2018

BILL0008, 222222, 1/30/2018

BILL0009, 222222, 3/1/2018

BILL0010, 222222, 4/2/2018

BILL0011, 222222, 5/3/2018

BILL0012, 222222, 6/1/2018

BILL0013, 222222, 7/1/2018

BILL0014, 222222, 7/28/2018

**Example output:**

Location: 111111           BlackOut: 6th - 11th

Location: 222222           BlackOut: 28th - 3rd

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you see if you can add some sample data and table structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited the original post with some additional information about the tables along with some condensed sample data.

Comment: *A picture is worth a thousand words.* It'd be pleasure to see some figure of your tables' relationships: Visio, Database Diagrams (in SQL Server) or some other figure.

Comment: I've deleted my poorly thought answer...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to work out the "average" day when the billing occurs and then construct a date range based around that?

The most accurate way I can think of doing this is to calculate a distance function and try to find the day of the month which minimises this distance function.
An example function would be:

> distance() = Min((Day(BillingDate) - TrialDayNumber) % 30, (TrialDayNumber - Day(BillingDate)) % 30)

This will produce a number between 0 and 15 telling you how far away a billing date is from an arbitrary day of the month TrialDayNumber.

You want to try to select a day which, on average, has the lowest possible distance value as this will be the day of the month which is closest to your billing days. This kind of optimisation function is going to be much easier to calculate if you can perform the calculation outside of SQL (e.g. if you export the data to Excel or SSRS).

I believe you can calculate it purely using SQL but it is pretty tricky. I got as far as generating a table with a distance result for every DayOfTheMonth / Location ID combination but got stuck when I tried to narrow this down to the best distance per location.

```
WITH DaysOfTheMonth as(
SELECT 1 as DayNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT DayNumber + 1 as DayNumber
FROM DaysOfTheMonth
WHERE AutoNumber < 31
)
SELECT Bills.LocationID, DaysOfTheMonth.DayNumber,
Avg((Day(Bills.BillingDate)-DaysOfTheMonth.DayNumber)%30) as Distance
FROM Bills, DaysOfTheMonth
GROUP BY Bills.LocationID, DaysOfTheMonth.DayNumber
```

A big downside of this approach is that it is computation heavy.